# High CPU Utilization in MySQL Database Server

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

I have to run a query which produces very large result set (20K result and 5 columns each row).

I am doing some processing on the data and storing the result in another database table.

All this processing is done on a cron process.

My problem is that when I run the query CPU utilization of my database server reaches up to 100% until the process finishes.

Please help me in understanding best practice for this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you need to start thinking about optimization and/or vertical scaling of the MySQL instance.

- Try to find a way to optimize the SQL query you're using
- If possible, split the cron job in several steps that execute lighter queries.
- If some of the data in the returned query set is identical on each cron run - cache it.
- If frequency of script execution is not of critical importance, split the runs and limit the query sets to a smaller number. You can execute the script 4 times in 20 minutes with 5k items in the query set.
- Think about migrating to a non-relational database, if possible.
- Do some performance tuning of the MySQL instance.
- etc.